# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед **и** в предложении: *я не хотел никого видеть, но эти парни были моими друзьями и нам было что обсудить*?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая перед союзом И ставится: **Я не хотел никого видеть, но эти парни были моими друзьями, и нам было что обсудить.**

**Пояснение**

Сложносочиненное предложение включает **три предикативные основы**, в то же время союз **НО относится ко второй и третьей основе**, то есть может рассматриваться **как общий элемент.** (Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом).

Однако У Розенталя есть примечание, говорящее о том, что противительный союз не может быть общим элементом, **поэтому запятая ставится.**

[§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится: Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых (П.);

Comment: Ответ есть: "поэтому запятая ставится", но он плохо выделен. Ответ содержит очень полезную информацию и мне кажется важным, так как он развеял все сомнения, которые у меня были по поводу общего элемента. Но, мне кажется, ответ выглядел  бы лучше, если бы был построен по-другому: сначало как правильно, а потом -  все рассуждения.

Answer (score 1):

Да, нужна, так как в предложении 3 основы: "я не хотел", "парни были", "было". Третья основа состоит только из сказуемого. Чтобы проверить, спросите себя, есть ли смысл у предложения "нам было что обсудить". Если смысл есть, значит, в нём есть основа.

Comment: Третья основа не "было", а "было что обсудить"...

Answer (score -1):

Запятая **нужна** ввиду *причинной связи* между двумя объединяемыми через "и" предложения - общий элемент в разной степени относится к этим предложениям (по смыслу его достаточно отнести только к первому). Смысл всего предложения не меняется при замене союза "**и**" на "**а**", "**поэтому**" или "**так что**" (в этих случаях необходимость в запятой более очевидна). То же можно сказать и о примерах, приводившихся по поводу этой запятой Розенталем в примечании к соотв. пункту. Однако, указав на решающую роль противительности союза "но", он не рассматривал примеров, в которых предложения с общим членом были бы взаимно независимы по смыслу. Например:

> Иван Петрович рассчитывал на хорошую погоду, но [к сожалению] вовсю
>   сверкала молния и в окно бились мокрые листья.

Здесь общий противительный союз ведёт себя как любой другой общий для двух предложений элемент (его можно чем-нибудь дополнить или заменить на что-то другое), поэтому запятая не нужна.

Comment: Откуда взят пример? И, между прочим, союзы не являются членами предложения.

Comment: Как все непросто! Получается, что Розенталь неудачно подобрал примеры к своему примечанию, и поэтому Alex_ander считает, что это примечание применимо не во всех случаях? Alex_ander, моя интуиция голосует за Вас, но формально Вы не правы.

Comment: Трудно согласиться с тем утверждением про общий элемент в  обсуждаемом предложении, что "по смыслу его достаточно отнести только к первому" простому предложению. Есть два вполне независимых предложения: (1) эти парни были моими друзьями, (2) нам было что обсудить (с этими парнями). Второе не следует из первого; замена "и" на "а", "поэтому" или "так что" меняет смысл фразы.